# Clicking the back button twice to exit an activity - Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, events

I know the question may sound weird, but I haven't found an exact answer. An android phone contains not only the back button, but also others. Almost all current games contain the "Press back again to exit" function, and this message appears not only at the click of the back button. I know very well how to detect the event for the back button in Unity, but with the others?
The funniest thing is that I didn't find a concrete answer for manipulating the 3 android buttons, but only for the back button, which is quite simple to implement.

For back button:

```
    int click = 0;
 void Update()
 {
     if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
     {
         click++;
         StartCoroutine(ClickTime());

           if (click > 1)
           {
               print("Exit Game!");
           }
     }
 }
 IEnumerator ClickTime()
 {
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
     click = 0;
 }
```

Okay, that's simple, but for the other buttons? Maybe I didn't search well, and if anyone has an idea where or how it is implemented as for the other buttons to display the message: "press back again to exit".
Thank you!

Comment: hmm .... then how did all the games implement this? somehow it's possible, but no one knows.

Comment: Seriously? that means you don't play games. It's not annoying, it does exactly the thing that makes it back button.Is it possible that it depends on the smartphone model? Why do I say, because I tested on a Xiaomi note 8 pro and this functionality persists, but not on a Huawei.

Comment: The same game on 2 devices, on Xiaomi if you press any of the 3 buttons, the message appears, but on Huawei it does not appear.

Comment: I didn't play any game that use the other 2 buttons on Android and I guess thats because it's something reserved for the OS only, because the far left button is for showing all my open apps and the middle one is for going home instantly. The back button is the only customizable to going "back" on the activity that you are currently doing.